# TCP ACK of packets in wireshark

Tags: http, wireshark, tcp

I've noticed in wireshark that I'm able to send 4096 bytes of data to a HTTP webserver (from uploading a file) however the server only seems to be acknowledging data 1460 bytes at a time. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of TCP segments is restricted to the MSS (Maximum Segment Size), which is basically the MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) less the bytes comprising the IP and TCP overhead.  On a typical Ethernet link, the MTU is 1500 bytes and basic IP and TCP headers comprise 20 bytes each, so the MSS is 1460 (1500 - 20 - 20).

If you're seeing packets indicated with a length field of 4096 bytes, then it almost certainly means that you're capturing on the transmitting host and Wireshark is being handed the large packet **before** it's segmented into 1460 byte chunks.  If you were to capture at the receiving side, you would see the individual 1460 byte segments arriving and not a single, large 4096 byte packet.

For further reading, I would encourage you to read Jasper Bongertz's blog titled, ["The drawbacks of local packet captures"](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2014/05/the-drawbacks-of-local-packet-captures/).

Comment: Makes sense. So that essentially means on the receiver side, that particular segment would've been splitted into 3 smaller packets with an effective data length of 1460 due to the MTU?

Comment: Right.  The sender is really sending Ethernet frames that are 1500 bytes (1518 bytes, if you count the framing bytes themselves) in size, with an effective TCP payload of 1460 bytes per frame.  That is what the server receives.  See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure

Answer (score 1):

TCP by default uses path MTU discovery:

- When system send packet to the network it set don't fragment flag (DF) in IP header
- When IP router or you local machine see DF packet that should be fragmented to match MTU of the next hop link it sends feedback (RTCP fragmentation need) that contains new MTU
- When system receives fragmentation needed ICMP it adjusts MSS and send data again.

This procedure is performed to reduce overall load on the network and increase probability of each packet delivery.

This is why you see 1460 packets.

Regarding to you question: the server only seems to be acknowledging data 1460 bytes at a time. Why is this the case?

TCP keep track window that defines "how many bytes of data you can send without acknowledge". Its purpose is to provide flow control mechanisms (sender can't send too much data that can't be processed) and congestion control mechanisms (sender can't send too much data to overload network). Window is defined by receiver side and may be increased during connection when TCP will estimate real channel bandwidth. So you may see one ACK that acknowledges several packets.